# Why is vscode giving me the error "No Inputs where found in file tsconfig.json" when tsc found none?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

This is the config file for my typescript project:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "js/app.js"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts",
        "src/bootstrap.ts",
        "libs/phaser.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "docs",
        "css",
        "index.html"
    ]
}
```

VS Code is giving me this error:

> file: 'file:///e%3A/Programming/TypeScript/tsconfig.json'
>   severity: 'Error' message: 'No inputs were found in config file
>   'e:/Programming/TypeScript/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include'
>   paths were '["**/*"]' and 'exclude' paths were
>   '["node_modules","bower_components","jspm_packages"]'.' at: '1,1'
>   source: 'js'

I googled the [Definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) for the tsconfig file, but I couldn't find the source for this error. What am I doing wrong here? When compiling it with tsc, everything is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered a similar error (thrown by VS Code) and the solution for me was to add a `.ts` extension to the file which serves as the entry point for my application. Typescript just needed something to compile ("an input").

Perhaps specifying the include path by adding

```
"include": [
   '**/*'
]
```

to your tsconfig.json will take care of it?

Comment: This error eventually went away when I added the node typescript compiler and stopped using the one coming with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Nice! It's an unusual bug and it seems like the fix is different for everyone -- glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem too, TypeScript didnt have anything to compile, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to `tsconfig.json` fixed it for me:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "rootDir": "./src",
  ...
}
```